# Need help finding logo font

Tags: logo, font-identification

I need help finding the font used in this logo, because I can font any results through whatisfont and myfonts. Help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Sometimes you need to edit an image to get font ID sites to work properly.  Try using [this image](https://imgur.com/oa3LLhW) in Whatthefont.com

Comment: "[B]ecause I can font any results": is that a pun? And if it is, shouldn't it be "I can't font"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, it's a bit of an iffy design. Either been compressed badly or was a bad font to start with. Lumps on DR, spine of the N too thick. Try Trade Gothic Condensed, or Relay Compressed if you want something a bit more geometric.